# Sliding window over a period of weeks in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sliding-window

I have a **dataset**:

```
+---------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|   Country     | Timezone  |Year_Week|MinUsers|
+---------------+-----------+---------+--------+
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-01  |4322    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-02  |4634    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-03  |5073    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-04  |4757    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-05  |5831    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-06  |5026    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-07  |5038    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-08  |5005    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-09  |5766    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-10  |5204    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-11  |5240    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-12  |5306    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-13  |5381    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-14  |5659    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-15  |5518    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-16  |6666    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-17  |5594    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-18  |5395    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-19  |5482    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-20  |5582    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-21  |5492    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-22  |5889    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-23  |6514    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-24  |5112    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-25  |4795    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-26  |4673    |
|Germany        |1.0        |2019-27  |5330    |
+---------------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I want to slide over the dataset with a window of **25 weeks** and calculate `avg min users` over the period. So final results should look like():

```
    +---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
    |   Country     | Timezone  |Year_Week|Avg(MinUsers)|
    +---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+
    |Germany        |1.0        |2019-25  |6006.12      |
    |Germany        |1.0        |2019-26  |2343.16      |
    |Germany        |1.0        |2019-27  |8464.2       |
    +---------------+-----------+---------+-------------+

    *Avg(MinUsers) are dummy numbers.
```

I want avg per country per timezone per yeark_week:

```
df
    .groupBy("Country", "Timezone", "Year_Week")
    .agg(min("NumUserPer4Hour").alias("MinUsers"))
    .withColumn("Avg", avg("MinUsers").over(Window.partitionBy("Country", "Timezone").rowsBetween(-25, 0).orderBy("Year_Week")))
    .orderBy("Country", "Year_Week")
```

Im not sure how to add the partition information there. I tried tumbling window as well but it didn't work well.

It would be great if someone can help in this regard.

Comment: Maybe you can show some code for what you tried and why it didn't work well...

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with a [Window Function](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(("Germany",1.0,"2019-01",4322),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-02",4634),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-03",5073),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-04",4757),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-05",5831),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-06",5026),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-07",5038),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-08",5005),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-09",5766),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-10",5204),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-11",5240),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-12",5306),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-13",5381),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-14",5659),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-15",5518),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-16",6666),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-17",5594),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-18",5395),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-19",5482),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-20",5582),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-21",5492),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-22",5889),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-23",6514),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-24",5112),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-25",4795),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-26",4673),
  ("Germany",1.0,"2019-27",5330)
).toDF("Country", "Timezone", "Year_Week", "MinUsers")

val w = Window.partitionBy("Country", "Timezone")
  .orderBy("Year_Week")
  .rowsBetween(-25, Window.currentRow)

df.select(
  $"Country",
  $"Timezone",
  $"Year_week",
  avg($"MinUsers").over(w).as("Avg(MinUsers)")
)
  .filter($"Year_Week" >= "2019-25")
  .show()
```

The filter is there to reduce the rows to the ones in your question, but the window function will calculate it for every row, ignoring when the number of previous weeks goes beyond the beginning of the dataframe. In those cases, it will calculate the averages with the rows that exist in that window.

The above code produces:

```
+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+
|Country|Timezone|Year_week|    Avg(MinUsers)|
+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+
|Germany|     1.0|  2019-25|          5371.24|
|Germany|     1.0|  2019-26|5344.384615384615|
|Germany|     1.0|  2019-27|5383.153846153846|
+-------+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a date field you can use the following code. You can replace days with weeks months year etc

```
spark.sql(
    """SELECT *, avg(some_value) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Country, Timezone 
        ORDER BY CAST(Year_Week AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS avg FROM df""").show()
```